# string binding in xaml is fine, but why BitmapSource binding is not?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, binding

In my application, I need to bind string and bitmapsource properties. the string binding works fine, but bitmapsource is not. It is sure that there are already image data by bitmapsource, as I can save it on disk. I also created a small project and both work fine.

xaml:

...

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyStringData" 
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:ImageProcess}" />

<Image x:Key="Txt" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyStringData}, Path=uri}" /> <!--uri is a string, it's fine -->
<Image x:Key="Txt" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyStringData}, Path=bms}" /> <!--bms is a BitmapSource, it's not fine -->
```

...

---

c#
        ....

```
    public string urii { set; get; }
    public BitmapSource bms { set; get; }

    ....
```

can anybody give me the reason?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These might be the answers:

- [Dynamic image source binding in
  silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213470/dynamic-image-source-binding-in-silverlight)
- [Imagebrush image source binding
  converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941111/imagebrush-image-source-binding-converter)

Comment: anatoliiG, thanks for the links you provided, but they are still not very helpful. My problem is: <Image x:Key="Txt" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyStringData}, Path=bms}" /> <!--bms is a BitmapSource, it's not fine in my application, BUT it's working in my simple test project! -->